# Custom hook not triggering component rerender despite changes in state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-hooks, react-context

**Context:** I have a custom hook that fetches firestore documents. It watches for document changes, then returns it and the loading state. I'm using this hook in another component.

**Problem:** Changes to the state values returned by the hook (`loading` and `document`) do not trigger the component using the hook to rerender and see the updated values.

**My Findings**: Other custom hooks work and trigger renders, so there must be something wrong with the `useDocument` hook. If another hook triggers a rerender, only then will `loading` finally update. The values of `loading` and `document` indeed update as expected within the hook, but a rerender of the component is still never triggered.

**Important Notes:** `useFirebase()` is a hook called within `useDocument` whose state is lifted up into context using the `constate` library. So technically this hook is a consumer of some provider higher up the tree that keeps track of the firebase libraries. This is to avoid unnecessary network calls.

```
export function useDocument() {
  const { auth, firestore } = useFirebase() // asynchronously fetches firebase modules
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true)
  const [document, setDocument] = useState()

  let unsubscribe = null

  

  useEffect(() => {
    let unsubscribe = null
    const watchDocument = () =>
      params?.query.onSnapshot(
        (doc) => {
          setDocument(doc.data() as T | undefined)
          setLoading(false)
        },
        (err) => {
          console.log(err)

          setError(err.message)
        }
      )
    if (firestore && auth?.currentUser) {
      unsubscribe = watchDocument()
    }
    return () => {
      unsubscribe && unsubscribe()
    }
  }, [firestore, auth?.currentUser])

  return {
    document,
    loading
  }
}

const MyComponent = () => {
  const {document, loading} = useDocument()
  console.log(loading) // changes to "loading" doesn't trigger rerender of this component
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are few mistakes in this snippet, the main one is that the variable `unsubscribe` is always `undefined` as its not even in the scope of the `useEffect`.

This might be a valid fix (never used firebase, just by looking at the code):

```
export function useDocument() {
  const { auth, firestore } = useFirebase();
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [document, setDocument] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    const watchDocument = async () => {
      const unsubscribe = await params?.query.onSnapshot(
        (doc) => {
          setDocument(doc.data());
          setLoading(false);
        },
        (err) => {
          console.log(err);
          setError(err.message);
        }
      );
    };

    let unsubscribe = null;
    if (firestore && auth) {
      unsubsribe = watchDocument();
    }
    return () => {
      unsubscribe?.();
    };
  }, [firestore, auth]);

  return {
    document,
    loading,
  };
}

const MyComponent = () => {
  const { document, loading } = useDocument();
  console.log(loading);
};
```

Comment: I deleted my original comment after digging deeper and seeing that I indeed defined unsubscribe in the wrong place. I updated my question with the correct code. Thanks!
The rerendering behavior ended up being a reference issue. I also realized I stripped out a little too much code in my question so I updated it to reflect where the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

So the issue is the dependency `auth?.currentUser`. `auth` itself properly triggers a re-render when state changes. The problem seemed to be that changes in `auth?.currentUser` is not detectable.

My assumption is that this is because `auth` is what is being tracked, and the reference to `auth` doesn't change even when `currentUser` is updated by the firebase library. I ended up moving `currentUser` into its own `useState`, and now the component properly rerenders.